# Why does a map on generators of a free associative algebra extend to an algebra homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\psi$ be the map of generators 
$\psi : \mathfrak{a}(2) \rightarrow \mathfrak{a}(2) \otimes \mathfrak{a}(2)$ where $\mathfrak{a}(2)$ is the mod $2$ Steenrod algebra.
$$\psi(Sq^k) = \sum_{i=0}^k Sq^i \otimes Sq^{k-i}$$
Let $\underline{\mathfrak{a}}$ be the free associative algebra generated by the $Sq^i \ (i>0)$. We have an epimorphism $\omega : \underline{\mathfrak{a}} \rightarrow \mathfrak{a}$ (writing $\mathfrak{a}(2)=\mathfrak{a}$), with kernel generated by the Adem relations. The map $\psi$ of generators extends naturally to an algebra homomorphism $\underline{\psi}: \underline{\mathfrak{a}} \rightarrow \mathfrak{a} \otimes \mathfrak{a}$.

Can you help me to explain about "**The map $\psi$ of generators extends naturally to an algebra homomorphism $\underline{\psi}: \underline{\mathfrak{a}} \rightarrow \mathfrak{a} \otimes \mathfrak{a}$."**

Comment: This question makes no sense without context (what is $\mathfrak{a}$? what are $Sq^k$? don't just answer "it's the Steenrod algebra"; it has several definitions). Are you still around to provide said context? If not, the question should be closed.